# How do you send a response of resolved promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, httpresponse

I have an array of links I want to get the response data from, populate an object with specific data from that response, and then send an array of objects with that response data through a route.

```
const apartmentObjectArray = apartmentLinks.map((link) => {
  helper.sendApartmentData(link)
});

res.send(apartmentObjectArray);
```

The problem I'm getting is that the response doesn't get resolved until after the response is sent. I've tried creating a variable before the response and assigning the objects to that variable but that doesn't work. Everyone I've asked has said that it's how asynchronous calls work, which is great that they can tell me that but they have not told me a solution to my problem.

```
function sendApartmentData(link) {
  axios.get(link).then(response => {
    parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
      const code = access(result, 'SearchResults:searchresults.message[0].code[0]');    
      if (code !== '0') {
        console.log('An error occured');
      } else {
        const resultArray = access(result, 'SearchResults:searchresults.response[0].results[0].result');
        resultArray.forEach(obj => {
          const dataObj = {};
          // populate dataObj...
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please don't tell me that `access()` performs an `eval`!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

This is a simple way to have a piece of code that is executed as soon as all the async operations you need to perform are completed. It also fails as soon as any of the async operations fail.

```
let apartmentDataPromises = [];
apartmentLinks.map((link) => {
    apartmentDataPromies.push(helper.sendApartmentData(link));
});

Promise.all(apartmentDataPromises).then(apartmentObjectArray => {
    res.send(apartmentObjectArray);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

function sendApartmentData(link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(link).then(response => {
            parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
                const code = access(result,'SearchResults:searchresults.message[0].code[0]');

                if (code !== '0') {
                    reject('An error occured');
                } else {
                    const resultArray = access(result,'SearchResults:searchresults.response[0].results[0].result');
                    resultArray.forEach(obj => {
                        const dataObj = {};
                        // populate dataObj...
                        resolve(dataObj);
                   });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It works partially. I think there's a problem where all the requests or dataObj are the same.

When I test the code on multiple links, (some have a response code of 0 [good] some have response code of 508[bad]), they all resolve to 508. The links themselves are not the problem either, I've tested them and they send the correct data (not just all 508 codes).

Comment: **edit Keeping true to your code all promises reject

Comment: Well, I might have miscopied some code. Sorry for that. If one of those operations fails, you desire to fail them all or not? Because if you don't want to, then you could replace the ´reject´ expression with a ´console.log´ and it should work.